# matlab determine curve

Tags: matlab

Does anyone know how to obtain a mean curve having a matrix with the correspondent x,y points from the original plot? I mean, I pretend a medium single curve.

Any code or just ideas would be very very helpful for me since I am new with matlab.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you show the code that produced this plot?

Comment: Obtain a mean curve really depends on how your data is stored...

Comment: The data i have is just a column with the x points and another with the y points. if i plot it, i obtain the plot i presented to you. any ideas? i would be so grateful!

Comment: So say you have N curves. You cannot really tell to which of the curves a certain point (x, y) belongs to, can you?

Comment: Yes, you can. But it is like this: each curve begins and ends in different points. imagine: the first one begins at (132,152) and ends at (128,162); and the second begins at (153,151) and ends at (132,166). so each curve is different from the other. and this information is took manually by me because what i have is two columns with x and y. (if you want me to give you the excel file, it would be my pleasure!) thank you very much again!

Comment: So how do you know where one curve starts and one curve ends?

Comment: I tought about the problem and i concluded i really cannot divide each cycle accurately and without mistake. so, i cannot say to which of the curves a certain point (x, y) belongs to. what i have is only a column with the x points and another with the y points. if you want me to give you the excel file, please just send me your email. it would be my pleasure. thank you very very much!

Comment: here they are two examples with correspondent data:http://www.speedyshare.com/Wedam/Livro1.xlsx.thank you very very much!

Answer (score 1):

Well, one thing you can do is fit a parametric curve. Here's an example on how to do this for a figure-8 with noise on it:

```
function findParamFit
    clc, clf, hold on

    %# some sample data
    noise = @(t) 0.25*rand(size(t))-0.125;
    x     = @(t) cos(t)    + noise(t);
    y     = @(t) sin(2*t)  + noise(t);

    t = linspace(-100*rand, +100*rand, 1e4);

    %# initial data
    plot(x(t), y(t), 'b.')        

    %# find fits 
    options = optimset(...
        'tolfun', 1e-12,...
        'tolx', 1e-12);

    a = lsqcurvefit(@myFun_x, [1 1], t, x(t), -10,10, options);     
    b = lsqcurvefit(@myFun_y, [1 2], t, y(t), -10,10, options);

    %# fitted curve
    xx = myFun_x(a,t);
    yy = myFun_y(b,t);   
    plot(xx, yy, 'r.') 

end

function F = myFun_x(a, tt)
    F  = a(1)*cos(a(2)*tt);
end

function F = myFun_y(b, tt)
    F  = b(1)*sin(b(2)*tt);
end
```

Note that this is a particularly bad way to fit parametric curves, as is apparent here by the extreme sensitivity of the solution to the quality of the initial values to `lsqcurvefit`. Nevertheless, fitting a parametric curve will be the way to go.

There's your google query :)

Comment: sorry, i don't want to abuse from your help. but can you tell me how can i apply this code to my excel file. i am very new with matlab and i know that i should do this but than i can't continue.